# Inter-App Communication to annotate documents in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, annotations, document, url-scheme

I have a customer with an Android app which he wants to be built in iOS. The android app has a feature in which the user can annotate documents. To achieve this the Parent app passes control to a third party Document annotation app, say Adobe reader for example where user annotates the documents and once he is done the control as well as the document is passed back to the Parent app. Is there any way i can achieve the same in iOS i.e pass control to a third party app to annotate documents from within my iOS App. 
I have read about URL schemes but that requires the third party app to make changes in their code which i dnt think anybody will agree to. So is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched all sorts of stuff. So finally the answer is NO.This can't be done in iOS without the third party app making changes in their Appdelegate file to handle the passed URL through URL schemes.